How to identify installed software on MacBook?
While checking the System report on my MacBook Pro (Sonoma 14.5), I found an installed third-party software under Software > Installations with Chinese characters (see attachment) that I do not understand. How and where can I get more information about this software?


Does it show up in Software->Applications?

@nohillside: no.

The Application can be sorted by date, does anything show up on June 22nd?

@nohillside: good idea: I found (many) updates on June 22nd via MacPorts but none with chinese letters.

It may not show up with chinese letters in the application list. But then it could also try to hide ...

I think Installations is data from /various/db/receipts -- or at least it used to be.

If you can COPY the Chinese characters you see you can paste them into Google Translate. I'm not betting on it but it might help identify it.

Live Text OCR on the Chinese characters and a web search show that it's an application called "Bear Markdown Notes" in the App Store.
